# Is there any way to hide filesystem path from error messages in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii-components

There is an application on production server, some times I need to make some quick modifications. However, Yii2, on errors, it display the full file system path of the buggy file.

The only things that I have know and tried:

1. Stop debugging in `web\index.php` like `defined('YII_DEBUG') or
   define('YII_DEBUG', false);`
2. Temporary close the website, like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413774/yii2-close-website-and-config), or for public (by changing bindings in IIS) and access it via internal loop from the remote desktop on the server.

I wonder if there is any way to make Yii stop regarding the full system path of the file and regard some general path such as `@app\views\site\index.php` instead of `C:\www\app\views\site\index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the method responsible on showing the errors is `renderCallStackItem` which is found in `vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php`. I just changed the file parameter that it returns as follows:

```
public function renderCallStackItem($file, $line, $class, $method, $args, $index)
    {
        $lines = [];
        $begin = $end = 0;
        if ($file !== null && $line !== null) {
            $line--; // adjust line number from one-based to zero-based
            $lines = @file($file);
            if ($line < 0 || $lines === false || ($lineCount = count($lines)) < $line) {
                return '';
            }

            $half = (int) (($index === 1 ? $this->maxSourceLines : $this->maxTraceSourceLines) / 2);
            $begin = $line - $half > 0 ? $line - $half : 0;
            $end = $line + $half < $lineCount ? $line + $half : $lineCount - 1;
        }

        return $this->renderFile($this->callStackItemView, [
            'file' => str_replace(Yii::$app->basePath, '...',$file), //Change is here
            'line' => $line,
            'class' => $class,
            'method' => $method,
            'index' => $index,
            'lines' => $lines,
            'begin' => $begin,
            'end' => $end,
            'args' => $args,
        ]);
    }
```

I have used `str_replace` to remove the basePath of the application from the error message. I have done this by hard coded the file in the framework source.

[image]

The problem now, I don't know how could I override the method in OOP? i.e I want to create new `ErrorHandler` class that extends from `vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php`. **The problem is how could I able to make Yii2 change its ErrorHandler class for the application wide?**

The solution is something like the following:

1- Change the default ErrorHandler class in `config/web.php`\

```
'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
            'class' => 'app\components\saidbakr\FoxErrorHandler',
        ],
```

2. Create a new class in `components/saidbakr` named `FoxErrorHandler.php` with the following code:

نتامعلخعرؤنلبغفخا

```
<?php
namespace app\components\saidbakr;

use Yii;

class FoxErrorHandler extends \yii\web\ErrorHandler
{
  public function renderCallStackItem($file, $line, $class, $method, $args, $index)
    {
        $lines = [];
        $begin = $end = 0;
        if ($file !== null && $line !== null) {
            $line--; // adjust line number from one-based to zero-based
            $lines = @file($file);
            if ($line < 0 || $lines === false || ($lineCount = count($lines)) < $line) {
                return '';
            }

            $half = (int) (($index === 1 ? $this->maxSourceLines : $this->maxTraceSourceLines) / 2);
            $begin = $line - $half > 0 ? $line - $half : 0;
            $end = $line + $half < $lineCount ? $line + $half : $lineCount - 1;
        }

        return $this->renderFile($this->callStackItemView, [
            'file' => str_replace(Yii::$app->basePath, '...',$file),//Look Here
            'line' => $line,
            'class' => $class,
            'method' => $method,
            'index' => $index,
            'lines' => $lines,
            'begin' => $begin,
            'end' => $end,
            'args' => $args,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The above class code is just inherited from ErrorHandler and the method `renderCallStackItem` is a copy of the original one with little modification on the `$file` value.

#### Update

In some cases the header of the error or debug message may contain the full filesystem path of the the affected file. It is a template called `previuosExceptionView` and it has a property in the `ErrorHandler` class called `previousExceptionView`. We should override this property in our children error handler class `FoxErrorHandler` like the following:

```
...
class FoxErrorHandler extends \yii\web\ErrorHandler
{
  public $previousExceptionView = '@app/components/saidbakr/previousException.php';
  
  public function renderCallStackItem($file, $line, $class, $method, $args, $index)
    {
....
```

Then, in the regarded path for `$previousExceptionView` we should copy a file called `previousException.php` from `\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\views\errorHandler` to that path i.e `@app/components/saidbakr/previousException.php`, then we have to edit its file path output, the file `previousException.php` should looks like the following:

```
<?php
/* @var $exception \yii\base\Exception */
/* @var $handler \app\components\saidbakr\FoxErrorHandler */
?>
<div class="previous">
    <span class="arrow">&crarr;</span>
    <h2>
        <span>Caused by:</span>
        <?php $name = $handler->getExceptionName($exception);
            if ($name !== null): ?>
            <span><?= $handler->htmlEncode($name) ?></span> &ndash;
            <?= $handler->addTypeLinks(get_class($exception)) ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span><?= $handler->htmlEncode(get_class($exception)) ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </h2>
    <h3><?= nl2br($handler->htmlEncode($exception->getMessage())) ?></h3>
    <!-- in the next line we are going to remove the full filesystem path and replace it with triple dots -->
    <p>in <span class="file"><?= str_replace(Yii::$app->basePath, '...',$exception->getFile()) ?></span> at line <span class="line"><?= $exception->getLine() ?></span></p>
<!-- End Edit -->
    <?php if ($exception instanceof \yii\db\Exception && !empty($exception->errorInfo)) {
        echo '<pre>Error Info: ' . print_r($exception->errorInfo, true) . '</pre>';
    } ?>
    <?= $handler->renderPreviousExceptions($exception) ?>
</div>
```